# remove the address in the cover letter in the moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I want to give some companies at the job fair tomorrow an general application without adding the address or the name of the company in the covering letter because I do not know which companies are going to be there. How can I remove it in the `moderncv`?

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual}
\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{Mustermann}
\familyname{Test}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Baumweg 28}{56334 Hamburg}
\mobile{0151/ 647 45 679 }
\email{mustermann.test@gmail.com}
\photo[3.5cm]{testimg}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage

\recipient{Company name Inc}{
Weltallee 8\\
11111  Berlin}
\date{\today}

\opening{%
\begin{center}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \bfseries Bewerbung um einen Arbeitsplatz als 
Informatiker
\end{center}%
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\closing{Freundliche Grüße,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

\begin{justify}

\bigbreak
\bigbreak

Mit freundlichen Grüßen, \\%\bigbreak
\bigbreak
Mustermann Test

\end{justify}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which style do you use?

Comment: Just saw it: casual, red

Comment: I had a look inside the moderncvheadi.sty . Maybe `\makeatletter \@detailsfalse \makeatother` could work. The casual seems to use the modercvheadi.sty .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on me:

```
\clearpage


\recipient{\ }{\ }

\date{\today}

\opening{%
\begin{center}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \bfseries Bewerbung um einen Arbeitsplatz als 
Informatiker
\end{center}%
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\closing{Freundliche Grüße,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle
```

The `\opening{}` requires `\recipient` not to be `\empty` or `\relax`. But it accepts a hard space `\`.